# Kicad: Drag with left button mouse click by default when working with Eeschema

Tags: kicad, eda

I want to change default behavior of left mouse click when working with Eeschema. Is it possible to change it from Move (M key) -> Drag (G key) when I select one/many elements?

I'm using KiCAD 5.0 on Mac.I have found below information:

- https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Kicad/eeschema/General_Commands

BUT **Ctrl + left mouse button** [Drag selection] does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you are unable to change the mouse behaviour.

I can attest that CTRL + left mouse button does certainly work. Hold control, drag a box around the symbol to be moved then release and you will be dragging the symbol.

Now with MAC I believe it would be command instead of control.

Comment: Hmmm....I can assure You CMD + LMB was not working yesterday... 
It is working now ;)
Gracias mi Amigo.

Comment: With open source software you are able to do anything.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: I suppose you are right @olltsu, but the general population won't be changing lines of code. Though maybe felixd would be interested in that. Can you provide information on how and where?

Comment: I have only looked through the kicad source code couple of times, when I wanted to scale down the scrolling on PCBnew. I got that done by modifying file *common/view/wx_view_controls.cpp*. However, it seems that controls in Eeschema are defined somewhere else, as my modification affected only PCBnew. But in any case, [here](https://github.com/KiCad/kicad-source-mirror) you can find the Kicad source.